# Doesn't understand a line that block server access

Tags: php, apache, http, xampp

I'm in a new company, and i have to install the wbesite of the company in a local server.
I install xampp on my windows 10, and i put all the company website in the htdocs.
But when i want to display a page, nothing is display.
I import all the BDD into my phpmyadmin.
I just see that all files begin with :

```
if(!defined('PROTECT') || PROTECT!=42) exit
```

And when i delete this line, some things are display like error far away in the file's code.
I dont know the line and i dont understand it.
Maybe it's protection from htacces or something like that and i want to know why nothing is display.
Thank you

Comment: there might a config file not getting included somewhere that has the definition for `PROTECT`

Comment: And do you know where might be the file ?

Comment: How would I know, I just guessed it. Is it a some well-known framework??

Comment: This checks if a constant of the name `PROTECT` is defined, and if it has the value 42 - otherwise, the script is exited right there. This is a mechanism commonly used to protect include files, that are not supposed to be called via HTTP directly, but only to be embedded by the “main” script.

Comment: Okay thank you i'll search more, beacause it's been 2 days since i want to display something and it doesnt work

Comment: There is probably a file with a line `define('PROTECT', 42);` that would be included in the bootstrap process of your code. This file might only be available in the live code. Just track the PHP top-down, line-by-line to see if there is any file-to-include that is missing. Or maybe its a part of the config or something. This is a really old style "security" practice in the realm of [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), a practice that should be obsoleted.